# Why does widget.resize() not work?

Tags: c++, qt, resize

My C++ code(use opencv and qt):

```
face_detect::face_detect(QWidget *parent)
: QWidget(parent)
{


imgwidget = new showwidget("D:\\sample.avi");
imgwidget->resize(QSize(640,480));


setWindowTitle(tr("Face Detection!"));





FaceNumLabel = new QLabel(tr("face_num：                                    "));
num = new QLabel;
num->setFrameStyle(QFrame::Panel | QFrame::Sunken);

ImgSource = new QLabel(tr("image source： "));

VedioBtn = new QPushButton(tr("from vedio"));
LocalImgBtn = new QPushButton(tr("local image"));

LeftLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
LeftLayout->addWidget(imgwidget);
LeftLayout->addWidget(FaceNumLabel);
LeftLayout->addWidget(num);
//LeftLayout->addWidget(ShowImageLabel, 3, 0, 1, 2);

RightLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
RightLayout->addWidget(ImgSource);
RightLayout->addWidget(VedioBtn);
RightLayout->addWidget(LocalImgBtn);
RightLayout->addWidget(ImgSource);

QHBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
mainLayout->addLayout(LeftLayout);
mainLayout->addLayout(RightLayout);
mainLayout->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetFixedSize);


connect(VedioBtn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(openvedio()));
connect(LocalImgBtn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(localimg()));
}
```

I call widget.resize() to resize the widget, and then add it to the layout. But when I run the program, the showimgwidget's is not 640*480. Why is that?

Comment: So, you set the size of your widget and then add it to a layout, basically asking it: Please position and resize this widget for me?

Comment: If you want to add a widget into a layout without it being resized, you must set its size policy to QSizePolicy::Fixed.